# Not displaying array elements by index

Tags: php, html

I wrote a php code for retrieving some data from a XML file into a variable.

This is the XML file:

```
<Server>
  <Server1>
    <ipaddress>10.3.2.0</ipaddress>
    <rootpassword>abcd</rootpassword>
    <port>22</port>
    <autousername>abcd</autousername>
    <autopassword>abcd</autopassword>
  </Server1>
  <Server1>
    <ipaddress>10.3.2.1</ipaddress>
    <rootpassword>abcd</rootpassword>
    <port>22</port>
    <autousername>abcd</autousername>
    <autopassword>abcd</autopassword>
  </Server1>
  <Server1>
    <ipaddress>10.3.2.2</ipaddress>
    <rootpassword>abcd</rootpassword>
    <port>22</port>
    <autousername>abcd</autousername>
    <autopassword>abcd</autopassword>
  </Server1>
  <Server1>
    <ipaddress>10.3.2.3</ipaddress>
    <rootpassword>abcd</rootpassword>
    <port>22</port>
    <autousername>abcd</autousername>
    <autopassword>abcd</autopassword>
  </Server1>
</Server>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("ipaddress");
```

Here i want to display the content of `$x` by index value, something like

```
echo $x[0]->nodeValue;
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Here you go http://php.net/SimpleXML :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you used `DOMDocument` for the XML parsing. When invoking `getElementsByTagName` you will receive a `DOMNodeList` not an `array`.

`DOMNodeList` implements `Traversable` so it can be used in `foreach` loops.

```
foreach ($x as $item) {
    var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
```

If you just want a specific item use the `item` method.

```
$x->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

***[The demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2iu1GY)***.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path_to_your_xml_file);
foreach($xml->Server1 as $server) {
  echo $server->ipaddress . '<br>';
}
```

Or you could just do:

```
echo $xml->Server1[0]->ipaddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay dear friend.But can I have an option for displaying value by index like $x[0], $x[1] like that

Comment: Since I don't want to display whole element.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `ipaddress` like below.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("yourxml.xml");
$result = $xml->xpath('//Server1');

foreach($result as $item){
    echo "IP Address:".$item->ipaddress
    echo "<br/>";
}
```